# What does "Type** variable" mean?

Tags: c

Can someone explain to me what the `**` after Cat is for?  If it's a pointer to a pointer, shouldn't there be a space?

```
    Cat fetch_and_kill_oldest(Cat** cat_array, int length){
    //This function tries to find the oldest cat, take away one life,
        Cat temp = cat_array[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < length; i++){
            if (cat_array[i].age > temp.age){
                temp = cat_array[i];
            }
        }
        temp.lives -= 1;
        return temp;
        //stop here
    }
```

Comment: In `Cat**` it means that the author has bad taste.

Comment: "If it's a pointer to a pointer, shouldn't there be a space?":  No space needed. `**` is not a token, so that parser recognizes it as two separate `*` tokens.

Comment: This is not a dup of the proposed question.  OP knows what the `**` operator is for, he just doesn't understand what it means when there's no space between it and the type name.

Comment: @vaultah No is not a duplicate. The OP doesn't ask what `**` means. Please read the Question Again. =>> `shouldn't there be a space?`

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
Cat** cat_array
```

Is the same as this:

```
Cat **cat_array
```

The latter is preferred because it's more clear what the pointers refer to.  For example, if you had a declaration like this:

```
int* a, b;
```

At first glance it might appear that `a` and `b` are both pointers, when in fact only `a` is a pointer.  By formatting it the following way it's more apparent:

```
int *a, b;
```